# segmentation fault in python mysqldb

Tags: python

I'm getting segmentation fault error when running a python file. When trace my code

```
python -m trace --trace file.py
```

I get this output :

```
 --- modulename: connections, funcname: set_character_set
 connections.py(292):         if self.character_set_name() != charset:
 connections.py(293):             try:
 connections.py(294):                 super(Connection,self).set_character_set(charset)

Segmentation fault
```

you can help me ? 
the other python files run correctly !

Comment: Are you using `MySQL-python` (unmaintained) or are you using `mysqlclient` (fork of the former, is maintained)?

Comment: I use **Mysql-python**